# MongoDB crazy slow when there is an $or inside of a query using an $and, How to get it to hit the index

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB collection with geocoded information in it.   In some cases I want to allow promoted items to be included that are not within the geographic area defined.  Below is an example of the query.

Takes about ~8500ms

```
{
    "$and": [{
            "After.Start": {
                "$gte": ISODate("2022-10-28T00:00:00Z")
            }
        },{
            "$or": [{
                    "LongLat": {
                        "$geoWithin": {
                            "$centerSphere": [[-111.888221740722, 40.760311126708999], 0.012616093290458801]
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    "ByPass": {
                        "$in": ["5162e"]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If I run this as two separate queries I can't add additional criteria or sort or page it correctly but it runs MUCH faster.

~61ms

```
{
    "$and": [{
            "After.Start": {
                "$gte": ISODate("2022-10-28T00:00:00Z")
            }
        },{
            "LongLat": {
                "$geoWithin": {
                    "$centerSphere": [[-111.888221740722, 40.760311126708999], 0.012616093290458801]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

~1ms

```
{
    "$and": [{
            "After.Start": {
                "$gte": ISODate("2022-10-28T00:00:00Z")
            }
        },{
            "ByPass": {
                "$in": ["5162e"]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have non compound Indexes on all three fields with the Index on LongLat being a 2dsphere.
I also have a compound index on LongLat and "After.Start".  Is there a different way that I can index this or perhaps store the data to add a ByPass.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$or` conditions test different fields, means one of them don't use indexes. Considering performance degradation it would be fair to assume the dataset is relatively large, and you have correct ByPass and geospatial indices.

You can check which indexes are being used with [explain](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/).

Comment: I've looked at the explain and it does use a different index for each clause of the $or currently but it's still slow after that.

Comment: @runxc1BretFerrier mind sharing what you've seen? Most of the answer is a guess work without explains for each query.